# "service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start" command not working?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

`Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager.service`

> Failed to start hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager.service: Unit not found.
>   cluster: Cloudera 5.14

Comment: Is that an error or what you have you tried

Comment: I tried to run command  "service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start"

Comment: I actually want to start yarn through command line in cloudera cluster 5.14

Comment: Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager.service

Comment: Failed to start hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager.service: Unit not found.

Comment: Do you know if you installed the service package for hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager?  Because the service packages are not installed by default.

Comment: what is command to install services packages ?

Answer (score -1):

may be Due to permission issue it is causing this issue.
sudo chown hdfs:hadoop -R /hdfs/data
sudo chmod 777 -R /hdfs/data
hadoop namenode -format
Run these commands from CLI and try 
it again.